# Is PHP OpenSSL library completely isolated and in no way linked with any OpenSSL binary on Ubuntu

Tags: php, openssl

We are using OpenSSL library provided by PHP.
But does this PHP OpenSSL library internally uses OpenSSL binaries that are probably provided as pre-compiled binaries with Ubuntu OS ?  Just putting in a doubt.

Just want to know that PHP OpenSSL library is completely isolated and in no way linked with any OpenSSL binary on Ubuntu ?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/openssl.requirements.php), it seems not to be using Ubuntu bundled OpenSSL and uses its own compiled [Openssl](https://www.openssl.org/) library as an extension.